# Usage of Microsoft .NET Source Code in my own program

Tags: c#, open-source, licensing, workflow-foundation

Am I allowed to use the (modify) sources of

```
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/
```

directly in my program or are the files for debugging purposes only?

There is a license file but English only and English isn't my native language so I don't really get it from the license file. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/license.html

Comment: _Use directly in my program_ is meaningless, unless you plan to modify it and in that case, as far as I know, this is not allowed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The license page should be clear:

> "Reference use" means use of the software within your company as a
>   reference, in read only form, for the sole purposes of debugging your
>   products, maintaining your products, or enhancing the interoperability
>   of your products with the software, and specifically excludes the
>   right to distribute the software outside of your company.

This means that you're allowed to use the sources only to debug, maintain and enhance your software. This doesn't mean that you're allowed to copy the source code and modify it for your purposes, because it's protected by copyright laws:

> (A) Copyright Grant- Subject to the terms of this license, the
>   Licensor grants you a non-transferable, non-exclusive, worldwide,
>   royalty-free copyright license to reproduce the software for reference
>   use.
>
> (B) Patent Grant- Subject to the terms of this license, the Licensor
>   grants you a non-transferable, non-exclusive, worldwide, royalty-free
>   patent license under licensed patents for reference use.